# Is there a way to implement the "expiration" time in a Firebase notification sent from php server?

Tags: php, android, curl, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I've implemented a php server that send Firebase Notification to users that are subscribed to a specific topic of my Firebase project.

It works.

In the console of Firebase there is the possibility to set the "expiring time" of the notification (from 1 minute up to 4 weeks).

Is there a method to insert this possibility also in my php server?

Thank you

Comment: As far as I know the expiration time in the Firebase Notifications console determines when Firebase stops trying to send the message to users. You could accomplish the same in your own code, by simply stopping to run the script (or putting a date check in there).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think you're looking for the [`time_to_live`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref#downstream-http-messages-json) parameter:

> This parameter specifies how long (in seconds) the message should be kept in FCM storage if the device is offline. The maximum time to live supported is 4 weeks, and the default value is 4 weeks. For more information, see [Setting the lifespan of a message](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#ttl).

Comment: Thank you, that is what I was looking!

Answer (score 4):

Send options with your request.

Set the message as high priority and have it expire after 10 seconds.

```
var options = {  
    "priority": "high",  
    "timeToLive": 10  
};
```

Send a message to devices subscribed to the provided topic.

```
admin.messaging().sendToTopic(topic, payload, options);
```